# How to resuse filters in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

In the Grails [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#filters), it reads that filter classes residing in `/conf` are picked up by convention.

We want to store all filters in a plugin; selectively configuring specific ones for use, but I can't find an example demonstrating this.

If this was my filter...

```
class ParameterManipulationFilters {
    def filters = {
        paramFilter(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (...) {
                    doSomething()
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...everything works fine when in `/conf`, but what to do if the filter resides in a plugin?

The [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) on Filters is light on spring beans related to this feature; not sure if `CompositeInterceptor` is something that I need to manually configure to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin may define a filter under `grails-app/conf/` in the same way that an application can.  If an application uses that plugin, by default that filter will be in play in the app.  You don't have to do anything special to make that happen.

You don't have to do anything at all with `CompositeInterceptor`.

As far as the selectively configuring which ones to use, you have a number of options.  One way you could do this is allowing the application to enable or disable filters in Config.groovy.

Consider a plugin named `alpha`.  In that plugin you define something like this...

```
// grails-app/conf/alpha/JeffFilters.groovy
package alpha

class JeffFilters {

    def isEnabled = true

    def filters = {
        // only configure the filter is if is enabled...
        if(isEnabled) {
            all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
                before = {
                    println 'JeffFilters.before is running...'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin can do something like this to enable/disable filters that it provides...

```
// AlphaGrailsPlugin.groovy
class AlphaGrailsPlugin {

    // ...

    def doWithApplicationContext = { ctx ->
        if(application.config.grails.myfilterconfig?.disableJeffFilter) {
            ctx.getBean('alpha.JeffFilters')?.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    // ...
```

}

By default the alpha.JeffFilters will be enabled.  The application (not the plugin) can disable that particular filter with something like this...

```
// grails-app/conf/Config.groovy

// ...
grails.myfilterconfig.disableJeffFilter=true
```

Of course you can orchestrate it the other way around so the at filters are disabled by default, if that makes more sense for your app.

I hope that helps.

Comment: looks good, btw, do filters implement an interface on which I can scan using `ctx.getBeansOfType(class)`? I'd rather search by class in `doWithApplicationContext` without knowing the filter's explicit name.

Comment: I don't think so but in `doWithApplicationContext` you can do something like `def filterNames = application.getArtefacts('Filters')*.name` or `def fullFilterNames = application.getArtefacts('Filters')*.fullName`.

Comment: Be careful if you are going to dynamically discover filter names and then impose the approach that I described in the answer above.  Of course not all filters are going to have the `isEnabled` property.  If you are going to go down that route you need to dynamically check if the property exists, or do something to deal with that fact.